# Python database access using single file/already build file

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have to save some data into MySQL from Python.

I have tried [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), but it needs to be built. Build fails on my Mac; moreover, I need to have one file to copy to server. I don't have access to install anything.

Can you recommend me any solution, please! Even where I can find MySQLdb build for specific platforms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One solution I'm thinking about is to use php for database access. But this is not elegant, temporary solution.

Comment: What difference would php do - it still will copy the file to the server in the same way python does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a [command line interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html) (similar to `psql` from Postgres or `sqlite3` from the database of the same name).  I would be surprised if this wasn't installed on the same server already.

You could then generate input for that utility using Python and call it with `subprocess`.  Depending on the data, this can be as simple as generating `INSERT` commands from scratch, or you can generate a temporary input file (e.g. in CSV format) and pass it to the utility by name.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to use C extensions from python on a Mac is to use [Macports](http://www.macports.org/)

Yo will need to install macports and then install the port py26-mysql this will install python 2.6 and MySQL.

However in this case I would have thought  MySQLdb should be an easy install - to help with that can you edit your question to show the error and tell us where the mySql libraries are installed

Comment: Can you give the actual error message and what file do you need to copy to the server - python mysql does not need more that a working MySQL on the server